# Referencing hash elements with symbol keys versus string keys

Tags: ruby, string, hash, symbols

How come ruby doesn't let you reference an element with either a string or a symbol unambiguously? This has often come up to bite me, especially when dealing with JSON. Doing

```
hash = {stat: bar}
```

allows for a reference by `hash[:stat]`. Later, if I did this:

```
hash = JSON.parse(hash.to_json)
hash[:stat]
```

that would return `nil`, and instead I would have to do `hash['stat']`. Why is that? Was this intentional, and if so, why?

Comment: If you really want to be able to use either, you can install ActiveSupport gem, and use its `HashWithIndiferentAccess`.

Comment: Of course it is intentional. Why would Ruby have strings and symbols in the first place if it did not distinguish them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON has no symbols. For property names, it only has strings. When you serialize a key/value pair to a JSON object, you lose any information about whether the key started life as a string or symbol, the key is just a string. When you deserialize the object back into a Ruby data structure, the only sane choice is to use strings for keys.

Comment: Alright thank you! That makes more sense. So one last thing- in my example, before I serialized into JSON, why is it illegal to call a string key when the key is a symbol?

Comment: It's not "illegal". You just didn't assign a value to that key, which means that it will return the default value, which is `nil` unless you set it to something different.

Comment: So the keys `:stat` and `'stat'` can coexist?

Comment: Of course. They're as different as `:stat` and `73`.

Comment: @dude0faw3: Yes, of course. `:stat` and `'stat'` are two completely different objects. They are not even of the same class, one is an instance of `String`, the other is an instance of `Symbol`!

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. This explains JSON's specification, but the question was about whether/why Ruby distinguishes strings and symbols.

Answer (score 4):

A hash maps key objects to value objects. If you associate a value object with a key object, you can retrieve it via that key object. If you associate a value with a different key object, you can retrieve it via that different key object. Passing one key object and getting the value of a different key object is just plain wrong.

Take, for example, the following hash:

```
hsh = {:foo => 42, 'foo' => 23, [:foo] => :bar, ['foo'] => :baz}
```

How would you retrieve either `42` or `23` if Ruby just willy-nilly started returning values for totally different keys?

Answer (score -2):

Symbol is parsed as string to json but the json parsed to hash will see it as string. If you gonna use it both ways, it's better to freeze the string instead of using symbols.